# How are you supposed to know which pyTZ is actually going to do as expected?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytz

So the following code in the shell illustrates the problem pretty well.  As I'm writing this, it is about 17:32 at (hence the 5:32)  But what does not make sense is why?

```
 >>> d = datetime.datetime(2015,3,15,13,0,0,tzinfo=pytz.timezone('America/Detroit'))
 >>> d.isoformat()
 '2015-03-15T13:00:00-05:32'

 >>> d = datetime.datetime(2015,3,15,13,0,0,tzinfo=pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))
 >>> d.isoformat()
 '2015-03-15T13:00:00-04:56'
```

And finally this works, but I don't understand why.

```
 >>> d = datetime.datetime(2015,3,15,13,0,0,tzinfo=pytz.timezone('EST'))
 >>> d.isoformat()
 '2015-03-15T13:00:00-05:00'
```

How are you supposed to know which TZ is actually going to do as expected?

Comment: [the very first note at the top of pytz docs](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) says that you should use `.localize()` method. I'm considering ways to improve the documentation. If you've read it; could you suggests a sentence or a paragraph that would strongly discourage `tzinfo` usage (via the `datetime` constructor or `.replace()` method) in favor of `.localize()` method?

Comment: I'd be inclined to use more boldface in that note to attract attention, and be pretty specific.  My choice to replace that first sentence would be "This library differs from the documented Python API for tzinfo implementations.  In particular, the tzinfo objects returned by this library **will not work as expected** as the tzinfo argument to datetime.datetime or datetime.replace.  You should instead apply the localize() method documented below to a naive datetime object. "

Comment: Though I did read PEP-431, and still don't understand why tzinfo doesn't work on times nowhere near the DST boundaries.  In particular, why you get these bizarre off-by-56-minutes times.  But I'm happy to follow the advice in the official answer.  And I'm glad datetime.now(tz) seems to work, since I don't know how I'd get it otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create a datetime by passing a value to `tzinfo=`. In your case the correct approach is to create a naive datetime and localize it:

```
>>> d = datetime.datetime(2015,3,15,13,0,0)
>>> pytz.timezone('EST').localize(d).isoformat()
'2015-03-15T13:00:00-05:00'
```

Similarly:

```
>>> pytz.timezone('US/Eastern').localize(d).isoformat()
'2015-03-15T13:00:00-04:00'
>>> pytz.timezone('America/Detroit').localize(d).isoformat()
'2015-03-15T13:00:00-04:00'
```